# Kivy ScreenManager does not switch screens (pure python)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm quite new to the Kivy and I have a problem which I couldn't resolve by myself.
I have a simple app where i want to switch between images (MainScreen).

This is the code:

```
IMAGE_SIZE = (640, 480)

class MainScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, path, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1])


        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Image(path)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
            self.bind(size=self.update_bg)

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')

        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def update_bg(self, *args):
        self.bg.pos = self.pos
        self.bg.size = self.size

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()
        if keycode[1] == 'enter':


            print('before enter', screen_manager.current_screen)
            screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            screen_manager.current_screen = scree_1
            print('after enter',screen_manager.current_screen)


        return True


screen_manager = None

scree_1 = MainScreen(path_1, name="1")
scree_2 = MainScreen(path_2, name="2")


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        screen_manager.add_widget(scree_2)
        screen_manager.add_widget(scree_1)

        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I did a print to see if something changes in screen manager:

[result of the print's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jAbX.png)

It seems to me that the manager indeed changes the screen, but I still the same picture.

I've already looked at this question and I found nothing helpful.

If anyone has an idea what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate any help/advice.

Update:

@JohnAnderson noticed in the comments, I should have swap the name of the screen, not the screen itself, however nothing changes ether.

Comment: You need to use the assigned `name` of the `Screen` in your `screen_manager.current =`. The names you have assigned are "1" and "2". So the line should look like `screen_manager.current = "1"`

Comment: You cannot directly change `current_screen'.

Comment: @JohnAnderson 
Yep, You are right, but I just corrected the name to be just "1", nothing changed.
_You cannot directly change `current_screen'_ - but what I can do ?
Actually, I would use the kv language for this purpose, but I found nothing about kv lang and keyboard events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must manipulate is `screen_manager.current` and not `screen_manager.current_screen`.
You must also refer to the `screen` by its name.

Here is your code, working:

```
IMAGE_SIZE = (640, 480)


class MainScreen(Screen):

    def __init__(self, path, **kwargs):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (IMAGE_SIZE[0], IMAGE_SIZE[1])

        with self.canvas:
            self.bg = Image(source=path)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
            self.bind(size=self.update_bg)

        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')

        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def update_bg(self, *args):
        self.bg.pos = self.pos
        self.bg.size = self.size

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard have been closed!')
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'escape':
            keyboard.release()
        if keycode[1] == 'enter':
            print('before enter', screen_manager.current)
            screen_manager.transition.direction = 'left'
            screen_manager.current = "1"
            print('after enter', screen_manager.current)

        return True


screen_manager = None

scree_1 = MainScreen(path_1, name="1")
scree_2 = MainScreen(path_2, name="2")


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        global screen_manager
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        screen_manager.add_widget(scree_2)
        screen_manager.add_widget(scree_1)

        return screen_manager


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found another answer.
I can also use:

```
            screen_manager.switch_to(screen_1, direction='left')
```